# JavaScript object indexOf, return parent position?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, indexof

Using `indexOf` to find the position of value "PO" in the object, I want instead to return the index position of the corresponding "properties" value. I believe the result should be 1, but I'm not getting any result.

What do I need to change? This has worked for me in other examples -- though I'm a beginner coder.

```js
myObj = {
    "type":"A",
    "info": [
        { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
        { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
        { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
    ]
}

var myObj, i, j, k, x = "";
for (i = 0; i < myObj.info.length; i++) {
    for (j in myObj.info[i].properties) {
    for (k in myObj.info[i].properties[j].id) {
    x = myObj.info[i].properties[j].id[k];
    a = x.indexOf("PO");
 if (-1 != a) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = j;
}
}
    }
    }
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: `j` isn't defined to anything. When you use it as a key in `properties` it returns `undefined`, and searching for the `id` of `undefined` results in an Uncaught TypeError

Comment: Thanks, I edited the snippet. Isn't it defined now? Sill no result.

Comment: For your information. There is no JSON in your code. JSON is a textual represenation of data. `myObj` is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Thanks for that edit, I was going to fix that. My actual problem uses JSON but I made it an object for this example to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative without findIndex()

```js
var myObj, i, j, k, x = "";

myObj = {
    "type":"A",
    "info": [
        { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
        { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
        { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
    ]
}

myObj.info.forEach(function(e, idx){
 if(e.properties.id == "PO")document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = idx;
});
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution -- this works. I was curious if my code had a potential solution with a small tweak, but perhaps it's relegated?

Comment: Also, what's the advantage of your solution vs. findIndex?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [**findIndex()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
const myObj = {
    "type":"A",
    "info": [
        { "item":"1", "properties":{ "id":"AL", "height": "25", width: "50" } },
        { "item":"2", "properties":{ "id":"PO", "height": "30", width: "40" } },
        { "item":"3", "properties":{ "id":"RA", "height": "20", width: "100" } }
    ]
}

const res = myObj.info.findIndex(info => info.properties.id === 'PO');
console.log(res);
```